# Figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering

I have a figure composed by 9 subfigures (3 rows and 3 columns). I divided this figure into 2 blocks using the following commands: `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` and `\addtocounter{subfigure}{1}`. These 2 blocs have the same label and the same figure number (Figure 1). I would like that the numbers of the 2 figures (blocs) become "Figure 1.1" and "Figure 1.2".
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post a minimal version of your document containing the code for the figures.

Comment: \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{subfigure}} or whatever counters you want to use.

Comment: <i>\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\subfigure[a]{
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}
}
\subfigure[b]{
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}
}
\subfigure[c]{
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig3.pdf}
}\\
\subfigure[d]{
....
}
\caption{title}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
\centering
\subfigure[...]{
\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig7.pdf}
}
...
\caption{title}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}</i>

Comment: Should those two blocks "stick" together? I mean, you don't want them to be separated but to form just one block, right?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I want to change only the numbering for these 2 figures(Figure 1.1 and Figure 1.2). 
These 2 figures are composed by subfigures. The other figures retain their numbering (Figure 2, Figure 3).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I want them to be separated. I explain in another way: I want that only 2 figures have the following numbers: Figure 1.1 and Figure 1.2. The other figures have the numbering: Figure  2, Figure  3, ...

Comment: @user49608 what I mean is that, since you used two `figure` environments for the blocks, there is the risk that one block ends in one page and the other one ends in a different page (due to flotation). I assume that you don't want this to happen (so I used just one `figure` environment in my answer) or do you admit this possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility using a temporal counter. For me it wasn't clear why you used

```
  \addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
```

but I respected this in my example codes below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcounter{tmp}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering 
  \subfigure[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfigure[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfigure[c]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig3.pdf}}\\
  \subfigure[d]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig4.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfigure[e]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig5.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfigure[f]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig6.pdf}}\\
  \refstepcounter{tmp}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{tmp}}
  \caption{title} 
  \label{fig:11}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \refstepcounter{tmp}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{tmp}}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1} 
  \addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
  \subfigure[g]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig7.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfigure[h]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig8.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfigure[i]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig9.pdf}}
  \caption{title} 
  \label{fig:12} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`subfigure` is an obsolete package which shouldn't be used anymore; in its stead you should use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). Here's the above approach, but using `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcounter{tmp}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering 
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig3.pdf}}\\
  \subfloat[d]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig4.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfloat[e]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig5.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfloat[f]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig6.pdf}}\\
  \refstepcounter{tmp}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{tmp}}
  \caption{title} 
  \label{fig:11}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering 
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\arabic{tmp}}
  \refstepcounter{tmp}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1} 
  \addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
  \subfloat[g]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig7.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfloat[h]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig8.pdf}}\hfill
  \subfloat[i]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth]{fig9.pdf}}
  \caption{title} 
  \label{fig:12} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: I can't put the 9 subfigures on the same page, they are large. So, I want them (blocks) to be separated.

Comment: @user49608 please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user49608 You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept an answer you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).